# How to make onBindViewHolder less expensive?[Android]

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, android-viewholder

**I read many articles about optimization and UI performance improvement of recyclerview. Their main point is make `onBindViewHolder` lighter.**

**List of issues I have :**

- My item layout has a `frameLayout` to show video with different width and height .I want to change the aspect ratio of frame layout according to video. My code inside `onBindViewHolder` is:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayout.getLayoutParams();
            if ((float) height / (float) width > (float) 1.25) {
                params.dimensionRatio = "4:5";

            } else {
                params.dimensionRatio = width + ":" + height;

            }
            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This is the cause of lag. I can clearly observe. Tell me `how instagram,Twitter show different ratio of video in their feed without lag`

- I have `custom recylerView` I'm creating a `viewHolder` instance inside it and performing some actions such as:

```
     addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull View view) {
        VideoAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (VideoAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.styledPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        holder.framelayout.addView(holder.styledPlayerView);
            }
```

I'm doing this inside the recyclerView class. I think it is a part of `onBindViewHolder` as the action is on current instance of viewHolder. here adding view to frame layout is expensive. How to handle this?

- I'm using `4 shape drawable`,`4 vector drawable` & `3 custom styles`. I can clearly see that when I'm using drawable it is lagging but after removing drawable the lag is decreasing to 40-50%

Comment: Don't put in `onBindViewHolder` things that are the same for all and aren't resources. Try to put it in ViewHolder constructor.

Comment: @cman My onBindviewholder has a seekbar listen, settings frame layout height and width for each item, a button to show the pop-up menu, a button to show the bottom sheet(nested)